# Client unable to bind to the given port and connect to the given server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, bind, connect

I need my client to bind to a particular port and then connect to its server. The problem is if I bind to the given port successfully but unable to connect to the server. If I don't attempt to bind to the port I am able to connect to the server. The below is my program:

```
int main()
{

    int sock, bytes_recieved;
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;

    host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(4000);
    client_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(client_addr.sin_zero),8);

    //host = gethostbyname("192.168.61.67");
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(2404);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))== -1)
    {
        perror("Unable to bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Client bound to 4000\n");
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected to the server\n");
    }

    while(1)
    {

      bytes_recieved=recv(sock,recv_data,1024,0);
      recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

      if (strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0)
      {
       close(sock);
       break;
      }

      else
       printf("\nRecieved data = %s " , recv_data);

       printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
       gets(send_data);
        if (strcmp(send_data , "q") != 0 && strcmp(send_data , "Q") != 0)
       send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);

      else
      {
       send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
       close(sock);
       break;
      }

    }
return 0;
}
```

In this program, If I use localhost for both the client and the server I am able to bind to the pot and connect to the server successfully. The problem appears if I give a different IP to the server. Kindly suggest any changes to the code to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are binding to the address `127.0.0.1`.  This address can *only* be used to connect to other loopback addresses.

Instead, you should be setting the `sin_addr` member of the bound address to `INADDR_ANY`:

```
client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Comment: I think it is client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need bind() in the client side. You do bind() in the server side.

This picture could help you understand

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:InternetSocketBasicDiagram_zhtw.png

***update1***

you can use instead

`client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to bind a client, for instance if the client is running behind a firewall that restricts the available ports the client can use, or when implementing certain protocols that use specific ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a client socket then you should not bind it. Assuming that you are creating a server socket then you should listen.

Here you are mixing both client and server concept

**Server**

```
SOCKET server=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
sockaddr_in local;
local.sin_family=AF_INET; 
local.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY; 
local.sin_port=htons((u_short)400); 

if(bind(server,(sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
 if(listen(server,10)!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKET client;
    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen=sizeof(from);

    while(true)//we are looping endlessly
    {
        char temp[512];

        client=accept(server,
            (struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);

        closesocket(client);

    }
```

**Client**

```
SOCKET conn;
conn=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
 sockaddr_in local;
local.sin_family=AF_INET; 
local.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY; 
local.sin_port=htons((u_short)400); 
if(connect(conn,(struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local)))
{
    //Send / Receive
    closesocket(conn);
    return; 
}
```

Comment: It is perfectly permissible to `bind()` a client socket, and there are sometimes reasons for doing so.